# CSS3, CSS Align toggle switch on an image

Tags: html, css

am having a problem aligning my toggle switch to an image, here is the exact description of what i need. http://jsfiddle.net/9M4gc/, my toggle switch is working accordingly but i just need to make use of CSS3 to align the toggle switch on the  image. view the picture below.

This the current looks of my page: 
[image]

An this how i want it:
[image]

Meaning that i just want the toggle switch to be on the image just like the image above. so far here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<div class="back" id="toggle"><br/>
<img src="http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/btn_push01c2x.png"/>
<label for="enjoy_web"></label>
<div class="slideThree">
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" />
<label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background:#088A08;
margin:auto;           
}


input[id=slideThree] {
visibility: hidden;
}

/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
width: 120px;
height: 45px;
background: #0101DF;

-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
position: relative;

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideThree:after {
content: 'OFF';
font: 19px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

.slideThree:before {
content: 'ON';
font: 19px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
z-index: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;

-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;

-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease;
-o-transition: all .4s ease;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .10s ease;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
left: 3px;
z-index: 1;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background: #fcfff4;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4',       endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
left: 68px;
}
```

A working Demo can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/9M4gc/ thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the image as a background, and position your toggle switch inside the parent div?

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/529Lk/

Comment: Hi Chris Hendry, i still have the same problem with this http://jsfiddle.net/9M4gc/ if you don't mind, can you explain to me what you changed to get it aligned properly. this particular one is has a smaller back ground and a smaller toggle switch button

Comment: In your .slideThree class add a left:200px; top:-10px; after your position:relative;

Comment: thanks Chris, i got to set the position using margins thanks for the reply.